# Getting to know related search queries from google

Tags: search, google-search

Are there any tools out there, that I can use to know popularly searched queries through google ? Say, if I want queries pertaining to iPhone battery or ios performance that people might have searched over time, is there anything similar to google trends that can lists related queries ?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean "Related Searches" that appear [at the bottom](https://imgur.com/a/XZKNl) of most google searches, you could try a pre-built library such as [a web scraper](https://serp-spider.github.io/) setup to specifically scrape these results.

You could also write your own scraper to pull these results, though you'll have to maintain the scraper as most likely Google will change it's markup over time.

Comment: I've been using google since god knows when, and it didn't strike me that I can use related search on google. This will work for the time being but it'd be extremely useful to know about other tools if they exist.

Comment: What better way to understand what people also search for then to consult the source of searches. There are a myriad of SEO related tools out there that will do this on an automated basis, and much more, for you - at a cost. If you can't afford their asking subscription prices then your other option is to write your own program to scrape related searches for you.

Comment: Yes I understand that. I'm wondering if there are related search queries based on frequency of search. Any idea which criteria google uses to suggest related queries ?